# image not updating in django from form post request

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to edit an object through the form

All fields are edited but the image field does not change

What is the problem?

**model created with signals when user create account**

**template**

```
 <div>
      <form action="{% url 'user:profile' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{form}}
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
  </div>
```

**model**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('RE', 'مشاور املاک'),
        ('S', 'فروشنده'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    real_estate = models.OneToOneField(Business , related_name='business' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True , null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    type_of_user = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=CHOICES)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique = True, null = False, blank = False)
```

**form**

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['type_of_user' , 'phone_number' , 'image']
```

**views**

```
def profile(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST , instance=profile)
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = request.user
        profile.save()
        redirect('busi:index')
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
    context = {
        'profile':profile,
        'form':form
    }

    return render(request , 'user/profile.html' , context)
```

Answer (score 1):

image is a type of file so you have to request files while requesting forms to be saved

```
def profile(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST , request.FILES, instance=profile)
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = request.user
        profile.save()
        redirect('busi:index')
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
    context = {
        'profile':profile,
        'form':form
    }

    return render(request , 'user/profile.html' , context)
```

also seems that you did not write a path for image to be stored in your model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('RE', 'مشاور املاک'),
        ('S', 'فروشنده'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    real_estate = models.OneToOneField(Business , related_name='business' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True , null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='profile_pics')
    type_of_user = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=CHOICES)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique = True, null = False, blank = False)
```

create folder name it as you want in media folder and code it there where image can be stored so django can look up for your image in that folder

Comment: yeah one more thing updating ans have a look

Comment: @AliRahmani please accept the anwser if it works for you